# Flutter add gradient colors on image

Tags: flutter

I need to add an image on the full background and then needed to add a gradient on the image. I have added the image in the background but the issue is not able to add the gradient colors.

My code.

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("images/sidebg.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 70, left: 10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Miroslava Savitskaya',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text('Active Status',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: drawerItems
                .map((element) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            element['icon'],
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(element['title'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                'Settings',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 2,
                height: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                'Log out',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

you can see in image here is background and some gradient color on image. I have added the image i want some gradient like in this image

Answer (score 1):

You can add gradient and blendMode to [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) in order to apply a gradient over the background image.